# Adjusting the Size of the Uploaded Image When Posting a Question

Tags: discussion, support, questions

How may one adjust the size of the displayed image when posting a question?

For example, I posted the following question yesterday:

[How to Draw a Rose in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570484/how-to-draw-a-rose-in-latex)

If I wanted to scale down the image of the rose a bit, how may I do that? Also, is it possible to reduce the size of an image offered as an answer? (For example, in my question, the user, gernot, posted a nice answer but the displayed image is even larger than mine!) It would be nice to be able to view the entire image someone posts without having to scroll through it.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is not specifically about TeX StackExchange. In fact, it has been [posted and answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/402142) on Meta StackExchange.